# GNU sed specify the end position when appending text

Tags: sed, gnu-sed

I want to do two things by `sed` when matching a pattern:

1. Replace the pattern with a string
2. Append another string after this line

Such as the original content in a text file is:

```
abc
123
edf
```

I want to replace `123` to `XXX` and append `YYY` after the line:

```
abc
XXX
YYY
edf
```

I tried to do this by `sed '/123/{s/123/XXX;a\YYY\}'`, but it gave an error: `Unmatched "{"`.

It seemed that command `a` treats all characters after it as ***text to append***. So how can I make `a` know the end position of the ***text for append***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/123/c\XXX\nYYY' file
```

This uses the `c` command to change the line matched by the pattern.

Or if you prefer to substitute and append:

```
sed 's/123/XXX/;T;a\YYY' file
```

Or:

```
sed -e '/123/{s//XXX/;a\YYY' -e '}' file
```

Or:

```
sed $'/123/{s//XXX/;a\YYY\n}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

It works the using actual newlines (tested with GNU Sed 4.2.2):

```
sed '/123/ {
    s/123/XXX
    a\YYY
}' < $input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` this could be the *simplest* one using `sed`:

```
sed  -e $'s/123/XXX\\nYYY/' file
```

From `bash` man:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands
>   to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by
>   the ANSI C  standard

**Example**

```
$ sed  -e 's/123/XXX\\nYYY/' file
abc
XXX\nYYY
edf
```

But `$'string'` will produce:

```
$ sed  -e $'s/123/XXX\\nYYY/' file
abc
XXX
YYY
edf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/123/XXX\'$'\nYYY/' a
abc
XXX
YYY
def
$
```

Where...

```
$ cat a
abc
123
def
$
```